# Regex matching across multiple lines with 3 values

Tags: regular-expression

I've seen a few examples of this, but I can't seem to get it to work in my particular situation.  Lets say there is the below file.

```
foo
line 1
line 2
line 3
bar
junk
junk
foo
line 1
line 2
baz
line 4
bar
```

I'm trying to catch everything between 'foo' and 'bar' as long as it contains 'baz' with a one liner.

Everything I've found so far is great for finding everything between foo and bar, but nothing seems to be good for only finding it if it contains baz.

Edit:  The below works for me:

```
sed -n '/foo/{:a;N;/bar/!ba; /baz/p}' input.txt
```

Comment: should `foo` and `bar` be also included into result?

Comment: `pcregrep -Mo '(?s)foo((?!bar).)*?baz((?!bar).)*?bar'` would do it in a not very efficient way.

Comment: Yes, I'll need the foo line.  foo is actually more like "foo data" with the foo part being static and the data something I need to see.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
/foo/ { save=1 }
/baz/ { p=1 }
/bar/ { if (p) { print out ORS $0; } p=0; save=0; out="" }
{ if (save) { if (out) { out = out ORS $0 } else { out = $0 } } }
' input
```

Start saving lines if we see a /foo/; decide that they're worth printing if we see a /baz/, and once we see a /bar/, print the saved lines if we saw a /baz/.

I can't find a smarter way to keep a blank line (ORS) from showing up at the beginning of the "out" variable without manually testing it (as I do).